# mysqldb environment

Tags: python, django, mysql-python

```
root@dicksonxavier-desktop:/home/dicksonxavier/Downloads/MySQL-python-1.2.3# python setup.py build
sh: mysql_config: not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "/home/dicksonxavier/Downloads/MySQL-python-1.2.3/setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
    libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
  File "/home/dicksonxavier/Downloads/MySQL-python-1.2.3/setup_posix.py", line 24, in mysql_config
    raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
```

Comment: apt-get install libmysql++-dev
this will solve this problem.[closed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the `mysql-devel` package or whatever your distro calls it.